# Not able to ban user on facebook page using c# graph api

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook page. I want to ban a user of the page using a graph api in C#.

I am able to block the user using graph api explorer but not able to achieve the same via graph api C# sdk.

I have also enabled all the required permission to block the user on page.

Currently using this query to block the user

```
{page-id}/blocked?user={user_id}
```

I have also tried to block the user using this method:

```
string blockUserPostRequest = "/" + pageId + "/blocked";
var parameters = new Dictionary<string,object>();
parameters.Add("user","49757260345454");
dynamic result = client.Post(blockUserPostRequest,parameters);
```

When I run the code using both the method I do not get any exception but it doesn't block the user as well.

Please guide me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: And you did use a page access token?

Comment: Yes I have used page access token.

Comment: Where did you get the user id from?